# Edit box does not gain focus in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-edittext

i'm facing wired problem in android when i try to focus for a EditText control.

In my application, i am dynamically adding the edit controls, whenever new control is added i wanted to 
give auto focus and popup the softkeypad automatically.

sometimes editbox get focus, but if i type text will not appear, sometimes text will appear in the other text control.

i'm observing this behaviour in my phone.

Here is my code snippet which i used to provide focus.

```
  if(mOldEditBox!=null)
            {
                mOldEditBox.clearFocus();
            }

            textView.requestFocus();
            //textView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); //to popup numpad
            //textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(focuschange); 
            mOldEditBox = textView;
```

i tried setting focuschangelistener event, still it didnt worked :(

```
OnFocusChangeListener focuschange = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){

                EditText txt = (EditText)v;

                //txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); //to popup numpad

                ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .showSoftInput(txt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

            }
        }
    };
```

Kindly help me where is the problem.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not on the UI thread when requesting focus which might cause the strange behavior of the EditText. Try adding it to the message queue using the `post(Runnable)` method:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right... brilliant & thanks too.. :)... just now i got it in Google its known issue.. we need to call this method after adding views to container...http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2705.. also to popup keyboard in this cases. ref this post http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/